# TFS 2018: How to put limit in task board?

Tags: tfs, task, scrum

I use TFS 2018 on-premises and created a project based on SCRUM process template.
I have successfully added some columns in task board.
Now I try to add limit on In Progress, Review and Test column (see following screenshot), but I find no setting for it. There is only setting for backlog items level, but what I want is **for sprint/task level**.

[image]

in the screenshot the red numbers are the limit I want to set.

Can anybody show me how to do it?
Any help and hint are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

WIP limits constrains the amount of work your team undertakes at each work stage. It's designed to focus your team on completing items before starting new work.

After define WIP limits for each work stage, corresponding to each intermediate column. The limit sets **a soft constraint** on the number of items allowed within the column. Nothing actually prevents you from moving more items into the column and exceeding the limit. Your Kanban board shows the count of items at each stage next to each limit.

**Taskboard** just provides a visualization of flow and status of each sprint task. With it, you can focus on the status of backlog items as well as work assigned to each team member. It also summarizes the total amount of remaining work to complete for a task or within a column.

*There is only setting for backlog items level, but what I want is for
sprint/task level.*

It's not related to backlog level, WIP limits only available in kanban board, to set this you must meet below prerequisites:

- You must have a Kanban board you want to configure. When you add a
  team, you add a Kanban board for that team.
- You must be added to the team administrator role for the team's
  settings you want to modify, or be a member of the Project
  Administrators security group.
- You must be granted Stakeholder access or higher.

### You are not able to put WIP limits in task board at present.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set wip limit for sprints. Only backlog (Kanban) boards support that: [Work in Progress limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/wip-limits?view=azure-devops)